# How to implement load while scrolling JList?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlist, javax

I don't know and can't find a method to add scroll listener to the JList.

I want to start "load more items" after scroll to bottom of the JList.

Which method can help me to implement it?

```
mListModel = new PlacementListModel();
mList = new JList<Placement>(mAdapter);
mList.setCellRenderer(new PlacementJPanelListCellRenderer());

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(mList);
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, 500));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add an `AdjustmentListener` the `JScrollBar` of the `JScrollPane`.

```
JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
vertical.addAdjustmentListener( ... );
```

When an event is generated you get the current value and compare it to the maximum value of the scrollbar. When it meets your criteria you then invoke your logic to load more items.

If you don't know how to write listeners in Java then check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html). There is no example for an AdjustmentListener the but concepts are the same for all listeners. In this case you just implement the `adjustmentValueChanged(...)` method. Start by just display the current value of the scrollbar each time an event is generated. You can also search the forum/web for examples that use an AdjustmentListener.

Comment: Can you post more detailed answer...There is an `AdjustmentEvent`, how to handle it? I'm a beginner in java. I know only Android